# Windows 10 stereomix audio recording distorted, peaks cut off/clipping

Tags: windows-10, audio, recording

The speaker sound is good but if I record via stereomix the recording sounds a bit different, distorted and the peaks are cut off. I've tested with 3 different recording software- Audacity, Vegas14 and Atube catcher. I always run into the same issue.

I've checked for Windows 10 Pro update and Realtek drivers in device manager. I also checked my mainboard manufacturer ASROCK website for [Z370 Extreme (mainboard)](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Z370%20Extreme4/index.asp#Download) new Realtek drivers but no new releases since 2018/8/9. I'm already running the latest versions.

Comment: Try a third-party tool such as Audacity which can change levels and compress audio as needed. See https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/, https://www.audacityteam.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

The clipping may be from having your output volume too high (the computer volume, not the powered speaker volume), try lowering it and checking the dB meter levels in your audio recording software: you want target 0 dB with no peaking into the red +dB area. Clipping is distortion (guitar fuzz effects basically clip to a square wave), so this will solve both issues.

The "stereo mix" option often has poor quality issues. It is unclear to me if "stereo mix" makes it to analog before being recorded, but I have seen comments that Windows' "WASAPI loopback device" "stays digital," usually in conversations about problems with stereo mix.

Try selecting "WASAPI Audio host" and the use the "loopback input" instead of "stereo mix" in Audacity.

https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_windows.html#wasapi

Comment: i pirmarily use atube catcher for video or sound recording. i just fired up vegas14 and audacity to confirm its not a software issue related to atube catcher. lowering the level for stereomix specificaly does reduce the sound volume in recordings but the distortion and cut peaks/clipping still persists. the setup isn't new and has worked flawless for the past 2 years, the sound distortion on stereomix recordings is new and i suspect one of the windows 10 updates in the past 2 months.

Comment: You can still try what k suggested with audacity as a way to *eliminate* it as a cause